# Desktop not recognizing monitors through USB-C docking station

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop, usb-c, docking-station

I have a work laptop and a personal desktop in my home office. I would like to be able to use my monitors and peripherals on both, ideally by just plugging the docking station into whichever one I'm using.

My desktop didn't have a USB-C port, so I had to take all the cables from my USB-C docking station (connected to the laptop) and plug them into a USB-3.0 docking station (connected to a desktop) and vice versa. This is not only irritating, but also a nightmare for cable management.

I decided to buy a PCI Express card with a USB-C port for my desktop, so that I could avoid all the hassle, but my desktop won't detect any monitors through the USB-C docking station (the peripherals all work).

I've tried installing drivers, as well as doing a power cycle reset (as recommended in similar threads) but neither has worked. Is there a solution, or am I doomed to using two docking stations?

I don't know if it's important, but the monitors are connected to the docking station using the following cables: 1) HDMI to HDMI, 2) HDMI to DisplayPort, 3) DisplayPort to DisplayPort. Also, My desktop OS is Windows 10.

I've considered trying to use the USB-3.0 docking station for both, but could this cause an issue? It's my work laptop and my IT knowledge isn't that great, so I don't want to take any risks.

Comment: You need to make sure that the USB-C card you purchased supports the protocols used by the dock. USB-C is a port shape, and there are multiple protocols that may run over that port. The dock is likely using either DisplayPort or Thunderbolt and your expansion card may not support these protocols.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for your quick response. Is it possible to use a USB-C to USB 3.0 converter, since I know USB 3.0 works?

Comment: That isn't particularly relevant to what you need to know. You need to know whether the dock is Thunderbolt or Display Port, or just USB3.

Comment: @user123965 Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @ShrapNull I didn't